# Laravel 5 View Not Found - Really Weird

Tags: php, git, debugging, model-view-controller, laravel-5

**Error message on live site**
Using laravel 5

```
InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 140:
View [comingsoon] not found.
```

Basically on production site I am getting an error message saying that the view is not found when it is clearly there. 
It works on my local server 100%. I recently just uploaded via the git repository so everything is in the same place. 

The folders all have 777 permission just to make sure that there was no permissions problem. 
I am at a loss as to why this could possibly be happening. I cannot seem to find any documentation online of people posting about this problem. 

Is there something in the config files which could be doing this. In the .env file maybe?

---

Comment: did you update composer? assuming you used composer....

Comment: yer composer is up to date, and everything within composer.

Comment: I did upgrade this project form laravel 4.2 to 5.0.28, if that makes any differnece?

Comment: That is a different problem. Sadly 4.2 to 5.anything was actually a big update. If you used specific functions in 4.2 that are no longer in 5.0 you are going to have a fail. This response doesn't exactly reflect that to my knowledge....

Comment: are all your other views working??

Comment: Well thats the thing... this is the main view which all other views go through. In the main resources/views/ folder.

Comment: I don't have any information now.... I'm unsure what to say.

Comment: hmmm... dam. thanks anyway.

Comment: in your config/view.php file what is the `paths` set to?

Comment: it may also be helpful to provide the relevant lines of code from your FindViewFinder.php file

Comment: That might be a stupid question to ask: But are you sure the file is tracked in your local repository? Maybe it's somehow ignored by git?

Comment: Right I found the solution to the problem. I think it had something to do with the apache case sensitive folders. Ill post how I fixed it below

Comment: It appears that within my views config. There was a line where `Resources` was specified as the directory, and the actual directory was `resources`. This was working on localhost probably because of case sensitivity stuff and not working on live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it might be the fact that your local environment has a case insensitive file system and production is case sensitive.